# Multiple 3D arrays to one 2D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have many 3D arrays in different files. I want to turn them into 2D arrays and then join them in 1 array.
I managed to get the 2D array, but not the format.
Ex:
Original 3D array of (4x2x2):

```
    [[[ 0  1]
      [ 2  3]]

     [[ 4  5]
      [ 6  7]]

     [[ 8  9]
      [10 11]]

     [[12 13]
      [14 15]]]
```

I want it to become 2D (2x8):

```
    [[0 1 4 5  8  9 12 13]
     [2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15]]
```

This is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    x=np.arange(16).reshape((4,2,2)) #Depth, Row, Column
    y=x.reshape((x.shape[1], -1), order='F')
```

If there is a better way to do this, please feel free to improve my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to swap the first two axes and then reshape, like so -

```
y = x.swapaxes(0,1).reshape(x.shape[1],-1)
```

Comment: Thank you! that was awesome. :)